# Xamarin Live Player does not connect after scanning barcode by mobile device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-live-player

I have tried to try new features of Xamarin live player but when I scanned the QR Code just scanned and did nothing.

1. I checked connection of all device and I am sure all device in same network.
2. I closed every thing  and re-start all device
3. I checked all available update.

In xamarin's web site write something like that "The network may be tightly secured (such as some corporate networks), blocking the ports needed by Xamarin Live Player."

How can I fix this problem do you have any idea guys ?

Comment: I'm hitting this exact same problem when using VS 2017 Community for Mac. I'm still attempting to troubleshoot

Comment: I changed network now the problem solved but now I have other problem. I cannot arrive to device in list I deleted it and scanned again but the problem still going on

Answer (score 5):

Phone and laptop must be on the same network.
From the same network you should be able to access internet (they provide no information for the purpos of this requirement)
They assume that your internal networking does not have port restrictions like firewalls. I observe that port 8084 is used by VS 2017.

> Your network might restrict port  **8090**

is the only port specific to Xamarin Live connection. 
This information is not officialy confirmed (there is a lot of fog around).

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95435/which-ports-are-needed-for-live-player

Other ports used by Xamarin are 80 and 443 and 5000:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/13862/ports-required-for-installation-behind-firewall

If you are on a Mac, For Xamarin Mac Agent port 22:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/firewall/

Comment: Very good information. I couldn't use my organization's WiFi and had to run a HotSpot from my personal phone to get VS and the iPhone connecting to each other.

Comment: Agreed @ChristopherBrown, i run my wifi and lan as separate networks. My PC has access to both. After disabling my ethernet connection and forcing my PC to run on the wifi network made things work the way they should. However, that's a lame solution - there should be a way to specify to Xamarin Live Player the network to utilize that my devices are connected to...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and fixed it by setting a custom port forwarding rule on my router for port 8090.  This site walks you through your specific router and how to set a custom rule:  https://portforward.com/router.htm

I had to set it for both my computer IP address and the phone's IP that I was trying to pair it with.  I'm not sure if that's how it's supposed to work, but only using one or the other didn't seem to work.